# WebStorm cannot save file when using ng serve

Tags: node.js, windows, angular, webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using `ng serve --open --live-reload` to serve an Angular app on my development machine, and using WebStorm to change the files I get the error "cannot save file" when WebStorm tries to save.

When I edit the file in Sublime I have no issues so it looks like the files are not locked by `ng serve`.

Dev setup

- Windows 10 host

  - WebStorm 2017.2.3
  - Sublime Text 3 3143
- Ubuntu running in WSL

  - `├─┬ @angular/cli@1.4.9
    │ └── @ngtools/webpack@1.7.4
    └── @ngtools/webpack@1.7.4`
  - `ng serve --open --live-reload`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was not ng serve locking files, nor any interactions between ubuntu and windows. It was the manner in which webstorm saves files by default.

By default webstorm will save a copy of the file with a tmp name, delete the original then rename your copy to be the same as the one just deleted. It looks like this process (which happens very fast) was interacting with ng serve in some odd manner causing the file to fail to be renamed leaving a funny tmp file behind.

The solution is to turn off 'Use "safe write" (save changes to a temporary file first)' in the 'system settings' under 'Appearance and behaviour' in the webstorm settings.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue specific to WSL, see [IDEA-173073](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173073): `Safe Writes` feature doesn't preserve original file permissions, causing problems when running on WSL. Workaround is disabling `Use "Safe write"` in *File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings*